# Multiplicación de vectores en mips assembler 2000

Tags: vectores, assembly, mips32

Intento multiplicar 2 vectores pero el producto de sus elementos me salen otros, ya intenté el codigo de abajo

```
.text
    .globl main
    main:
    lw $t1,cont0
    lw $t2,cont1
    la $t4,vector1
    la $t5,vector2
    la $s0,vector3
    lw $t7,cont0
    
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,msg
        syscall
       
        li $v0,5
        syscall
        move $t3,$v0  

    jal funcionsolicitarvector
    jal funcionsolicitarvector1
    jal multiplicacion
    jal imprimirvector
    
    li $v0,10
    syscall

    funcionsolicitarvector:
            vector:
            bgt $t2,$t3,sigue
        
            li $v0,4
            la $a0,msg1
            syscall
        
            li $v0,5
            syscall
        
            move $t0,$v0
        
            sw $t0,($t4)
        
            addi $t4,$t4,4
            addi $t2,$t2,1
            j vector
            sigue:
            lw $t2,cont1
            
            jr $ra
        
    funcionsolicitarvector1:
            vector10:
            bgt $t2,$t3,sigue1
        
            li $v0,4
            la $a0,msg2
            syscall
        
            li $v0,5
            syscall
        
            move $t0,$v0
        
            sw $t0,($t5)
        
            addi $t5,$t5,4
            addi $t2,$t2,1
            j vector10
            sigue1:
            lw $t2,cont1
        
            jr $ra
            
        multiplicacion:
            addi $t4,$t4,-4
            addi $t5,$t5,-4
            bucle:
            bgt $t2,$t3,seg
            
            lw $t0,($t5)
            lw $t1,($t4)
            
            addi $t2,$t2,1
            mul $t6,$t0,$t1
            sw $t6, ($s0)
            addi $t4,$t4,-4
            addi $s0,$s0,4
            addi $t5,$t5,-4
            j bucle
            seg:
            lw $t2 ,cont1
            jr $ra
        imprimirvector:
            mul $s1,$t3,4
            sub $s0,$s0,$s1
            Mientras:
            bgt $t2,$t3,sigue2
            lw $t4,($s0)
            
            li $v0,1
            move $a0,$t4
            syscall
         
            li $v0,4
            la $a0,coma
            syscall
         
            addi $t2,$t2,1
            addi $s0,$s0,4
            j Mientras
            sigue2:
            
            jr $ra
     
   
            
            
.data
    cont1: .word 1
    cont0: .word 0
    msg: .asciiz "Ingrese el número de elementos de los vectores: "
    msg12: .asciiz "Ingrese el número de elementos del segundo vector: "
    msg1: .asciiz "Elemento del vector 1: "
    msg2: .asciiz "Elemento del vector 2 : "
    vector1: .word 0
    vector2: .word 0
    vector3: .word 0
    coma: .asciiz ","
```

Por ejemplo  con los vectores 1,3,3,6,5,1 y 5,4,8,9,5,5 me salen que el producto es 25-45-405-1125-125-5- pero obviamente está mal, además no se porque no reconoce ni la coma.